# Calculating volume of a rotation of function

Tags: calculus, integration

Let function be $f:[0,\frac{\pi}{4}]\rightarrow \mathbb{R} , f(x)=\tan^n(x), n\in\mathbb{N}$

So i want to calculate volume of what appears, when u rotate the function around x axis.

So i know the formula $V=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\pi f^2(x)dx$ but i don't know how to apply it because of $n$, or is it just using it that way and looking for different $n$?
Also should i be careful of how that function looks in the interval $[0,\frac{\pi}{4}]$?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The general idea is that rotating the curves for $\tan x$, $\tan^2 x$, and $\tan^3 x$ may give you three different volumes; since $n$ could be any integer, the answer won't just be a number but will be some expression involving $n$ so that it would give the correct volume no matter what value of $n$ you tried; sort of like the way $1+2+\ldots+n=n(n+1)/2$ is a correct formula no matter what natural number you substitute for $n$.

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle V=\int_0^{\pi/4}\pi\big(\tan^{n}x\big)^2\,dx=\pi\int_0^{\pi/4}\tan^{2n}x\,dx$, so let $u=\tan x,\;x=\tan^{-1}u,\;dx=\frac{1}{u^2+1}du$ to get

$\displaystyle V=\int_0^1\frac{u^{2n}}{u^2+1}du=\int_0^1\left(u^{2n-2}-u^{2n-4}+u^{2n-6}-\cdots+(-1)^{n+1}+(-1)^{n}\frac{1}{u^2+1}\right)du$

$\hspace{.17 in}\displaystyle=\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n-3}+\frac{1}{2n-5}-\cdots+(-1)^{n+1}+(-1)^n\frac{\pi}{4}$

$\hspace{.17 in}\displaystyle=(-1)^{n+1}\left[1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\cdots+(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{\pi}{4}\right]$

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation of the solution of $@$user84413.

We combine the geometric series with the formula
\begin{equation*}
\Psi'(z) = -\dfrac{1}{z}-\gamma + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{k}-\dfrac{1}{z+k}\right)
\end{equation*}
where $\Psi$
is the digamma function and $\gamma$ the  Euler constant. Then we get
\begin{gather*}
V = \pi\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{u^{2n}}{1+u^{2}}\, du =  \pi\int_{0}^{1}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}u^{2n+2k}\right)\, du = \pi\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{k}}{2n+2k+1} =\\[2ex]
\pi\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{2n+4k+1}-\dfrac{1}{2n+4k+3}\right) = \dfrac{\pi}{4}\left(-\dfrac{1}{n/2+3/4}-\gamma + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{k}-\dfrac{1}{n/2+3/4+k}\right)\right) -\\[2ex]
\dfrac{\pi}{4}\left(- \dfrac{1}{n/2+1/4}-\gamma + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{k}-\dfrac{1}{n/2+1/4+k}\right)\right) = \dfrac{\pi}{4}\left(\Psi\left(\dfrac{n}{2}+\dfrac{3}{4}\right)-\Psi\left(\dfrac{n}{2}+\dfrac{1}{4}\right)\right).
\end{gather*}

**Remark.** This solution works even for other $n$ than positive integers.